# make open() return when signal is caught

Tags: c, linux, signals

When I call `open("./fifo",O_RDONLY)`, the syscall will block because no one is writing to the fifo `./fifo`. If a signal is received during that time that has no signal handler, the process ends instantly. So far so good.
But when a signal is received that has a signal handler, the signal handler is executed and the `open()` syscall is still blocking.

How can I make `open()` return when I catch the signal?

I tried to block the signal, that does not work because there is no `sigmask` argument for `open()` like there is for `pselect()`. Using `O_NONBLOCK` does not work either, because then `open()` will return with an error, whether there is a signal or not. Removing the signal handler is also no good because I want to be able to react to the signal.

My test code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static volatile bool end=0;

static void catchSignal(int signal)
{
  (void)signal;
  const char *s="Catched Signal\n";
  write(STDERR_FILENO,s,strlen(s));
  end=1;
}

static int openFile(void)
{
  int fd=open("./in",O_RDONLY);
  if(fd<0)
  {
    perror("can't open file");
    exit(1);
  }
  return fd;
}


int main()
{
  if(SIG_ERR==signal(SIGTERM,catchSignal))
  {
    perror("cant set up signal handler");
    return -1;
  }
  int fd = openFile();
  while(end==0)
  {
    puts("Still running");
    usleep(300UL*1000);
  }
  puts("End now");
  if(fd>0)
  {
    close(fd);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `signal()` function is problematic because of a history of implementations with different details. According to [its Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html):

> The  only  portable  use of `signal()` is to set a signal's disposition to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`.  The semantics when using `signal()` to establish a signal handler vary across systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits this variation); **do not use it for this purpose**.

(Emphasis in the original)

Instead of `signal()`, you should be using `sigaction()`:

```
  struct sigaction sa = { .sa_handler = catchSignal };

  if (SIG_ERR == sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL))
```

Note that among the fields of a `struct sigaction` is `sa_flags`, a bitmask with which you can select among the various behaviors historically implemented by different versions of `signal()`.  In particular, if you do not include the `SA_RESTART` flag, as the above indeed does not, then you should not see system calls automatically resume when interrupted by a signal (except for those few that are explicitly specified to do so).

Answer (score 0):

When you `strace` your program, you see that signal() functions sets SA_RESTART flag for the signal:

```
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x562f2a8c3249, sa_mask=[TERM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fb504d2d210}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
```

meaning, that the open() syscall will be automatically restarted after handling the signal.

You can use [sigaction()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to have more fine-grained control over signal handling and not set the SA_RESTART:

```
struct sigaction sa;
memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
sa.sa_handler = catchSignal;
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
if (sigaction (SIGTERM, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
  perror("sigaction");
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `O_NONBLOCK` in which case `open()` will return immediately, and you will block as soon as you `fcntl(2)` cancelling the `O_NONBLOCK`.

Read the man page, as probably you have some way to make `open(2)` return `-1` and `errno` equal to `EINTR`.  But the normal usage is what has been described, the call is reissued, so the signal handler doesn't make the calll to be interrupted (much code depends on this behaviour).  I'm not sure about this, but I think only `pause(2)` and `select(2)` and friends are interrupted (and return) when a non-ignored signal is received.

Is worth noting that only the thread that is blocked in an interruptible call and receives the signal is awaken and the call interrupted, and the thread receiving the interrupt can be any of the ones  you have started in your process.